# traffic splitting in google app engine based on customer subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine

When customers signup to my service (myservice.com), they get assigned a subdomain. So customer A would get a url to customerA.myservice.com, customer B would get a url like customerB.myservice.com etc.

I am working on a new version of the service, and would like to redirect some of the new customers to the new version to test the new version.

I know I can create different versions of the service, and split the traffic by ip and cookie between them. It is also possible to split traffic based on routing, but it seems, that in the end GAE still relies on either ip or cookie information to split the traffic: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting#Routing. So if my customer accesses the my service on desktop, ipad and smartphone, he might sometimes get one version of my service on his desktop (at home) and another on his smartphone (on the road).

So my question is if it is possible to always direct customerA.myservice.com to one version of my service and customerB.myservice.com to another version, regardless of device, cookie or ip?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with Traffic Splitting feature of App Engine, but you can implement this logic yourself. When users hit your domain, you can choose which version of the app to serve them. There are three drawbacks:

1. It won't look pretty - the URLs pointing to individual versions may be confusing.
2. Users might bookmark the version URL, and later they will get an error when they hit it, if the version is no longer available.
3. You have to make sure that all URLs in your app are relative, if they point to your domain. Otherwise you might link across different versions.

Also, some versions may not be compatible due to the changes in the data model, i.e. you cannot run them in parallel.

Similar issues also arise with the App Engine's splitting - or any other traffic splitting. This is why I recommend to have a trusted group of your most enthusiastic users. Send them a new version as a "preview" and ask for their feedback. They will appreciate you reaching out to them, and they will not be confused if they hit a different version on a different device.

Comment: Reaching out to the most enthusiastic users sounds like the right way to go then. Thanks for your feedback !